# How to install firewall script in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router/Firewall

In the link above there is a firewall script described. How can I install this script in Ubuntu 10.0.4 desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The “advanced” firewall script is a shell script that is supposed to be executed after both the internal and the external interface are up.

First, put the script somewhere, say `/etc/init.d/local/my_firewall_script`, make it executable, and add `#!/bin/sh` as the first line in the script file.

Next, you need to arrange for the script to run after both interfaces are up. You have two options:

- through upstart. This has my preference because the script must run when both interfaces are up. Create a file `/etc/init/my_firewall.conf` containing something like this:

  ```
  description "My firewall script"
  start on (net-device-up IFACE=br0 and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
  console output

  pre-start exec /etc/init.d/local/my_firewall_script
  ```

  This is completely untested, and I have zero upstart experience, so you may need to adapt the file. Also there's a [bug related to the net-device-up event](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/497299) that might affect you.
- through ifup scripts. This is a bit fiddly here because the script must be run when the second interface comes up. Create a file `/etc/network/if-up.d/my_firewall` containing something like this (unstested):

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  if [ "$IFACE" = "br0" ] || [ "$IFACE" = "eth0" ]; then
    if [ -n "$(ip addr show br0 | grep '^ *inet ')" ] 2>/dev/null &&
       [ -n "$(ip addr show eth0 | grep '^ *inet ')" ] 2>/dev/null; then
      /etc/init.d/local/my_firewall_script
    fi
  fi
  ```

  If there was a single interface, or if there was a guarantee that one of the interfaces always came up after the other, this method would be simpler and preferred: the script would be (assuming the single or last-up interface is `eth0`):

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  if [ "$IFACE" = "et0" ]; then
    /etc/init.d/local/my_firewall_script
  fi
  ```

Note that the script given there is fairly specific to a particular setup — it's an example of a relatively advanced script. You'll have to adapt it to your setup, at least the IP address ranges and probably the name of the interfaces.

After you've found a method that works, I suggest you write a description of how you did it to the wiki page.

Comment: I tried the second way, no good. If I run firewall script from shell then I see the rule is added. However right after boot the rule is not there. Is there any way to log something to /var/log/messages from the script, so I can have some clue why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Michael: add `set -x; exec >/var/tmp/ 2>&1` to the top of the ifup script. What happens if you do `ifdown eth0; ifup eth0`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some comprehensive documentation which provides several options you can choose from:

> [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Configuration on startup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Configuration%20on%20startup)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the script as `/etc/iptables.up.rules` for example and add:

```
post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

to `/etc/network/interfaces` file under the definition of your interface.