# DD-WRT in bridge mode

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dd-wrt, bridge

I already have router which is Ubuntu PC. I need to connect my DD-WRT asus router WAN to Ubuntu routing PC in the way so DD-WRT will just bridge connection between wireless and WAN interfaces. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you wanting to bridge wirelessly or wired?

Comment: neither one, I just want dd-wrt to pass through the traffic from WAN to wireless interface, so for instance my notebook with Wifi can get DHCP from Ubuntu, use internet sharing from Ubuntu, avoiding double NATing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your other [post](https://superuser.com/questions/184540/how-to-install-firewall-script-in-ubuntu) along with this, my first questions back to you is why do you have your ubuntu PC running as your router?  DD-WRT has really good protocol for firewall protection.  Bridging a connection from your Ubuntu Desktop PC to a DD-WRT router will not be impossible, but I feel that you will have more success with having the router directly connected to you ISP.

With that said, DD-WRT has guides on how to place the router into a "repeater" mode [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge).  Follow those instructions and you'll be able to forward the connections of the router and attached devices to the ubuntu machine.  This is not a "bridged" connection, but rather using the router as a simple "repeater" that sends the packets both ways.  You will then need to share the internet connection of the ubunut pc by following [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing) instructions.

Comment: still router hardware is weak comparing to PC hardware for my internet connection. Performance is going down dramatically with router and if I connect Ubuntu to my internet cable performance suffer much less. Besides I run FTP server and connecting NTFS(yes, I need it) HDD to SATA is much reliable than connecting through USB to dd-wrt. There are more reasons that I want to give ubuntu a try as router. However, in the link you provided network topology is different than I want. I am not going to bridge two networks, instead just use router's Wireless link to pass-through traffic.

Comment: I understand that you do are not wanting to bridge two networks, however the link describes hot to place the dd-wrt router into a repeater mode, which just repeater traffic both directions.